# Need to add a search to static HTML site using javascript

Tags: javascript, web, static

anyone can help me to implement a search field for a static website, my website doesn't have a database, it's only HTML and CSS.

I want to be able to search files with extension .html in a specific folder called post.

Inside the post folder, there are many files with extension .html

I want to search these files through input field using javascript and output the URL in a div

Comment: This is far too broad a question for a site that helps people work out issues in their code. Plus it appears you haven't done any research. Here's one option: https://support.google.com/programmable-search/answer/4513903?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

```
            <div id="search">
                <form name="searchForm" action="http://google.com/search">
                  <input name="query" type="text" value="" placeholder="search" maxlength="250" />
                  <input name="query" type="hidden" value="site:yoursiteurl"/>
                  <input id = "submitButton" name="submit" type="submit" value="Search" />
                </form>
              </div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).